# Is there a web link to Source Code of the Blender "patch" for Otoy Octane Renderer's version of Blender they bundle with their GPU rendering Plugin?

Tags: 3d, rendering, gpu, render, blender

According to this link:
https://home.otoy.com/render/octane-render/demo/

The demo they give must use the BLENDER version they give you which that page only has links for binaries it seems. But since Blender is GPL, there must be a link to the "source code" somewhere, maybe hidden and harder to find? Anyone know where they put that link to the source code of the Blender version they are distributing? Otherwise as far as I know it is quite a blatant and severe license violation to distribute modified BLENDER 3D version in binary form only.

I am not asking for any opinion, I am asking for a "LINK" to the SOURCE-CODE of the BLENDER binary they are distributing on that website, if someone has a link.

Of course I also downloaded and installed their modified version of BLENDER and I could not find any info in splash screen or help-about with source-code link.

So if anyone has the link please post it, I searched but I just didn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Doing some more searching I found a repository on Github but seems 5 YEARS OLD.

https://github.com/OTOY-NZ/OctaneBlender

So if someone has a CURRENT updated source code link please update here. I don't know why they don't link to source code where they distribute binary or why I can't seem to find a link in their modified installed version of blender.

Comment: Octane is an external render engine. From the otoy home page click support, then additional plugins and you will find the docs for [octanes blender plugin](https://docs.otoy.com/BlenderH/BlenderPluginManual.htm). Also the current version supports alembic, so you could export your scene to an alembic file to open it in octane.

Comment: I don't know if they changed it recently but although Octane is an EXTERNAL render engine, it required that you run a SPECIAL version of BLENDER called "OctaneBlender". And because Blender is GPL, Otoy must legally provide the "full source code" to every version of "OctaneBlender" that they release, not source code for their actual external "PLUGIN" that does the rendering but for their version of Blender, called "OctaneBLENDER". Hope that clarifies.